# What would be the best way to bevel an oval table top?

Tags: technique, power-tools, wood, sanding, tabletop

I'm building an oval dining room table and I'm looking for ideas on the best way to add a 30deg. bevel to the top. The top is 42" x 76". The top will be solid 4/4 Ash.

I was thinking maybe a belt sander? I added an image of the top below. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand upon @keshlam's answer, you're going to want to purchase a chamfer or low angle bevel bit.  [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H2AFK3I) (among others) sells a 60-deg bevel bit (pictured below), and chamfer bits can be found at just about any woodworking supplier.

[image: 60 deg bevel]

You will notice that this bit has a guide bearing on it, which is crucial for the bit's function in this type of operation.

My advise to you would be to make this bevel in lots of shallow cuts.  If you try to hog off the entire bevel at once, the results *will not* be pretty (and actually a little dangerous).

> I was thinking maybe a belt sander?

A belt sander would work, yes, but it will not be anywhere near as consistent, convenient, or quick as using a router.

Comment: Is there a router bit large enough to do a bevel of that size? The landing on most of the bits I have seen was only 3/4" to 1" or so.

Comment: @ChrisHeichel, you might have to do some searching now that you know what to look for.

Comment: I see. My only concern with using a router was tear out once I started moving it towards the end grain. If I do shallow cuts like you suggested, do you think this would still be an issue?

Comment: So long as you work the router that the grain is running "downhill" from the cut, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: You could, with care, use the belt sander to hog off some of the bevel, then finish nicely with _fewer_ passes of the router bit. Draw lines on the top and the edge of where you expect your final bevel to be, then stay well clear of these when working with the sander.

Answer (score 3):

Common solution would be a router with an edge-guided bit.